# What type of econometrics is practised most?

Tags: econometrics, time-series, causality

This might sound like a weird question, but what type of econometrics is most common in academia and / or the private sector?

Here I am thinking about time series econometrics (Bayesian and Frequentist) on one side, vs what I would call Microeconometrics (not necessarily tied to only microeconomic issues) - i.e. quasi experimental methods and establishing causality - on the other. (Maybe this is the wrong way of drawing a line or there should be more lines drawn between different areas in econometrics. Than I am happy to adjust my question.)

I have been at 2 unis now where people claimed that there is literally no research with time series stuff going on. At the same time, the place where I did my undergrad seemed to have focused especially on Time series stuff (at least my teachers did). On the other hand, I would guess that most private sector jobs (and central banks) would want someone that does forecasts and other time series methods.

Does anyone have a few wise words on the demand for econometric methods and what type is more common where? I guess there is no clear answer for all of the world, but is there some countries / regions for which one can answer this question? Also can this question be answered for big agencies like the world bank, the IMF, the ECB or the OECD?

Comment: this question should be narrowed down to some field I doubt it is possible to objectively answer what is the most used econometric method across whole academia no matter what topic and in addition even private sector

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will change the question.